# Recording notes next to an Excel query

Tags: excel, issue-tracking, vba

I want to be able to make notes next to an Excel query that pulls in incidents from a database. Currently, I have the notes included in the table, but when an incident is moved to another area the notes do not follow the correct row.

This is the code i'm using to include the notes column into the table

```
Sub IncludeNotes()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_query")
    lo.Resize lo.Range.Resize
    lo.HeaderRowRange.RowHeight = 65

End Sub
```

I'm looking to make these notes when reviewing the incidents that move to different tiers and solution areas.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach outlined at Matt Allington's post on adding comments to bank statements. Too complex to reproduce here, but it uses PowerQuery, so you'll need to have Excel 2016 (which has PowerQuery baked in) or install the free PowerQuery add-in for Excel 2010/2013.